# How to set image count per page using flicikity slider

Tags: javascript, css, flickity

I am using flicikity slider for homepage. My problem is, I can't set more than 4 images per page.

I read the document fully. I can't find the perfect answers.

I used siema package there is an option called "perPage: 1", this option solved my problem. But there is no option like this. Also, I tried some CSS tricks like reduce `width` & `height` size. But there is no use.

Answer (score 0):

I think they automatically add slider on each div
see the codepen solution here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel"
  data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": true }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 66%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}


.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I think you forget to add codepen link.

Comment: It was showing unable to add codepen link https://codepen.io/prashen/pen/LYYgLrX

Comment: @PrakashT If it helps you please don't forget to make the answer accepted. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry. your solution not helped for me.

Comment: Please provide some example code on codepen or somewhere. It's difficult to understand the scenario.